# How to read json with fields without values as spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am working with Json files  on spark-dataframe. I am trying to parse file with below Json Strings:

> {"id":"00010005","time_value":864359000,"speed":1079,"acceleration":19,"la":36.1433530,"lo":-11.51577690}
>   {"id":"00010005","time_value":864360000,"speed":1176,"acceleration":10,"la":36.1432660,"lo":-11.51578220}
>   {"id":"00010005","time_value":864361000,"speed":1175,"acceleration":,"la":36.1431730,"lo":-11.51578840}
>   {"id":"00010005","time_value":864362000,"speed":1174,"acceleration":,"la":36.1430780,"lo":-11.51579410}
>   {"id":"00010005","time_value":864363000,"speed":1285,"acceleration":11,"la":36.1429890,"lo":-11.51580110}

Here acceleration field sometimes don't contain any values.Spark is marking those json as Corrupt_record which dont have acceleration value.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(data)
scala> df.show(20)
+--------------------+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----+----------+
|     _corrupt_record|acceleration|      id|       la|         lo|speed|time_value|
+--------------------+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----+----------+
|                null|          -1|00010005|36.143418|-11.5157712|  887| 864358000|
|                null|          19|00010005|36.143353|-11.5157769| 1079| 864359000|
|                null|          10|00010005|36.143266|-11.5157822| 1176| 864360000|
|{"id":"00010005",...|        null|    null|     null|       null| null|      null|
|{"id":"00010005",...|        null|    null|     null|       null| null|      null|
```

I dont want to drop these records. What would be the correct way to read these Json records?

I have tried below code and replaced "acceleration" with '0' value. But its not generic solution to handle scenario where value for any field can be missing.

```
val df1 = df.select("_corrupt_record").na.drop()
val stripRdd = df1.rdd.map( x => x.getString(0)).map(x=>x.replace(""""acceleration":""",""""acceleration":0"""))
val newDf = sqlContext.read.json(stripRdd)
val trimDf = df.drop("_corrupt_record").na.drop
val finalDf = trimDf.unionAll(newDf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily if you have a schema in place for your record, say you schema is called SpeedRecord with fields : acceleration, id, la, lo, speed, time_value

```
case class SpeedRecord(acceleration : Int, id : Long, la : Double , lo : Double, speed : Int, time_value : Long)

val schema = Encoders.bean(classOf[SpeedRecord]).schema
val speedRecord = spark.read.schema(schema).json("/path/data.json")
speedRecord.show()
```